# How to update the status based on Precedence?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have status combolist:

```
Agents
Association
conf.delegate
Embassies
exhibitors
Ing-advert
Inquiry
Low Priority
Misc
PrioAdvert
Priority
Removes
Sec-Advert
Secondary
Service Provider
VIP
VIP Exhibitor
VIP Visitor
Visitors
```

I want a query in such way that:

`Misc` status change(update) to `Secondary/visitor/priority/Agents/Assciation/Inquiry/Exhibitors/Removes/Embassies/VIP/VIP exbitors/VIP visitors`

But `Secondary/priority/visitor/Agents/Assciation/Inquiry/Exhibitors/Removes/Embassies/VIP/VIP exbitors/VIP visitor` should not change to `Misc`.

Same way `Secondary` status change to `visitor/priority/Agents/Assciation/Inquiry/Exhibitors/Removes/Embassies/VIP/VIP exbitors/VIP visitors`

But `visitor/priority/Agents/Assciation/Inquiry/Exhibitors/Removes/Embassies/VIP/VIP exbitors/VIP visitors` should not change to `Secondary`.

I have written the following query in a stored procedure which updates the status to anything which I want.

```
set 
  cmp.status= 
    case when 
      cmp.status='' OR 
      cmp.status IS NULL OR 
      cmp.status IS NOT NULL 
    then  
      dupl.status 
    else 
      cmp.status 
    end 
from companyinfo cmp
inner join #DuplTempTable dupl on cmp.ID=dupl.ID
```

I don't have an idea how to write the update query according to precedence. I know that I have to use  `CASE WHEN` to achieve it.

Comment: I don't understand at all. You have a table named `companyinfo` that has a `status` column. In one row the status column may contain the word 'Misc' and you want it to contain the string 'Secondary/visitor/priority/Agents/Assciation/Inquiry/Exhibitors/Removes/Embassies/VIP/VIP exbitors/VIP visitors' instead? Or what else?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner...This all are a status(dropdownlist).Say,suppose user selected status Misc from the dropdownlist(combolist) and saved it.If he wanted to change the status from Misc to Seconday then it should change.But Suppose user selected status Secondary from dropdownlist and saved it.if he wanted to change the status from secondary to Misc then it should not be change.(As Secondary status has the higher precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
update cmp 
set 
  cmp.status= 
    case when 
      cmp.status='' OR 
      cmp.status IS NULL OR 
      cmp.status IS NOT NULL 
    then  
      dupl.status 
    else 
      cmp.status 
    end 
from companyinfo cmp
inner join #DuplTempTable dupl on cmp.ID=dupl.ID
```

Comment: @Muhammad...this is the samw query which i have written..but this updates the status to anything ...I want it according to precedence...like higher precedence status should not be updated to lower precedence status

Comment: I thought you are just confused with syntax -_-